# Update sliderInput in Shiny reactively

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to change the values from a `sliderInput` dynamically. The difficulty now is that I want to change from a `sliderInput` with one value, to a `sliderInput` with a range, which seems not to work.

The first actionbutton in the code below works, while the second does not what it is intended to do.

Is the only possibility to switch to an `uiOutput` element?

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
app <- shinyApp(
   ui = bootstrapPage(
      sliderInput("sld1", min = 0, max = 10, label = "y1", value = 5),
      actionButton("acb1", "Change Value"),
      actionButton("acb2", "Change Value to Range")
   ),
   server = function(input, output, session) {
      observeEvent(input$acb1, {
         updateSliderInput(session, "sld1", value = 2)
      })
      observeEvent(input$acb2, {
         updateSliderInput(session, "sld1", value = c(2,7))
      })
   })
runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can maybe add the slider dynamically using `renderUI`

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    uiOutput("myList"),
    actionButton("acb1", "Change Value"),
    actionButton("acb2", "Change Value to Range")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    slidertype <- reactiveValues()
    slidertype$type <- "default"

    observeEvent(input$acb1,{slidertype$type <- "normal"})
    observeEvent(input$acb2, {slidertype$type <- "range"})

    output$myList <- renderUI({

      if(slidertype$type == "normal"){
        sliderInput("sld1", min = 0, max = 10, label = "y1", value = 2)
      }
      else if(slidertype$type == "range"){
        sliderInput("sld1", min = 0, max = 10, label = "y1", value = c(2,7))
      }
      else{
        sliderInput("sld1", min = 0, max = 10, label = "y1", value = 5)
      }
    })    
})
runApp(app)
```

Comment: Well, that's what I thought, I have to rely on `uiOutput` - thanks fro the worked out example though with a good use case of `reactiveValues`