# Making reactive variables for interactive shiny widget parameters

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to make a histogram of a weights dataset(df)  subsetted by a group specification named 'kit'. The app should have an action button to submit a text input field to specify the kit grouping for the dataset and a 2-way Inputslider which will eventually display two vertical lines on the histogram. Because the weight ranges vary so much from kit to kit, I'd like the sliderInput bounds be interactive, updating to be a bit beyond the min and max weights of the subsetted dataset.

I tried to implement it using a uiOutput call in the ui function and updating the widget and histogram parameters with creating reactive variables with the reactiveValues option ala this example [Update sliderInput in Shiny reactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863663/update-sliderinput-in-shiny-reactively).

UI FUNCTION

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

df =  data.frame(list(x = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20,5,3), z = rnorm(20,5,.4) )) %>% gather(key = 'kit', value = 'weight')

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      em('Select a kit and a weight range for it.'),
      textInput('kit', strong('Enter Kit Number'), value='107066'),
      actionButton('kitSelect','Select Kit'),
      uiOutput('slider'),
      sliderInput('bins','Number of Bins', min = 5, max = 30, val= 15)
     ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('hist')
      )
    )
  )
```

SERVER FUNCTION:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    kitSelect = reactiveValues()  

    observeEvent(input$kitSelect, {
      #subset data by kit
      kitSelect$histdf = df %>% filter( kit == input$kit)  %>% select(weight)
      weightrange = range(kitSelect$histdf)[2] - range(kitSelect$histdf)[1]
      #min and max parameters for slider buttons
      kitSelect$a =  range(kitSelect$histdf)[1] - weightRange*.1
      kitSelect$b = range(kitSelect$histdf)[2] + weightRange*.1

      #bin width for histogram
      kitSelect$width = (b-a)/input$bins
    })

    output$slider = renderUI({
      sliderInput('slider', 'Kit Range', min = kitSelect$a, max = kitSelect$b, value = c(kitSelect$a, kitSelect$b))
    })
    output$hist= renderPlot({

      ggplot(kitSelect$histdf, aes(x= weight)) + 
      geom_histogram(color = 'blue', fill = 'blue', alpha = .5, binwidth = kitSelect$width) +
      stat_bin(aes(label = ..count../dim(dfHist)[1]), geom = 'text', vjust = -.5)+
      scale_x_continuous( breaks= seq(kitSelect$a, kitSelect$b, width)) +
      stat_function(fun=dnorm, n =501, args = list(mean = mean(kitSelect$histdf), sd = sd(kitSelect$histdf)))

  })
}
```

I get a 'subscript out of bound' error in the renderUI call and I don't know what that means.

Comment: I see the problem but there are other ones. `df$kit` is a character vector made of the letters x,y,z. Thus `filter(kit == input$kit)` gives a table with 0 rows.

Comment: `input$kit` is a string input specifying the kit group - x,y or z -- for df to be subsetted by.  I ran my code above and that statement returns  20 observations as expected. So that shouldn't be the problem. Once I do the subsetting I'd like for the default inputSlider parameters to update to new min/max bounds appropriate to the new subsetted data.